# Does ruby has a feature like socksProxy in java?

Tags: ruby, proxy

When I write a program in java, I use -`DsocksProxyHost`, `-DsockProxyPort` options to proxy all my network request to the specified address.

Does ruby has a feature like that?
I know there are `Proxy` class in ruby. However, I do not think I can utilize it when I want to connect to oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with JRuby using the `-J` flag which passes options to the JVM:

```
jruby -J-DsocksProxyHost=domain program.rb
```

MRI/Rubinius don't have a similar flag, but you can use a gem like [proxifier](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-proxifier) or [socksify](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/) to do the dirty work for you.

Comment: I did not check whether the solution works. However it looks perfect answer. Thanks!